# What is lazy loading in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, lazy-loading

What is lazy loading in Java? I don't understand the process. Can anybody help me to understand the process of lazy loading?

Answer (score 280):

Say you have a parent and that parent has a collection of children. Hibernate now can "lazy-load" the children, which means that it does not actually load all the children when loading the parent. Instead, it loads them when requested to do so. You can either request this explicitly or, and this is far more common, hibernate will load them automatically when you try to access a child.

Lazy-loading can help improve the performance significantly since often you won't need the children and so they will not be loaded.

Also beware of the n+1-problem. Hibernate will not actually load all children when you access the collection. Instead, it will load each child individually. When iterating over the collection, this causes a query for every child. In order to avoid this, you can trick hibernate into loading all children simultaneously, e.g. by calling parent.getChildren().size().

Comment: Alternatively Hibernate.initialize(parent.getChildren()) should be used

Comment: The statement "when you access the collection ... it will load each child individually" is actually completely inaccurate.  Its actually the exact opposite.  Any dereference of parent.getChildren() will cause Hibernate to load all the children in the collection in one db query.  Unless you used the very special "extra lazy" lazy loading hint.  Or unless you cache the collection in second level cache and the associated children are not also cached.

Comment: Oh, Stack Overflow - best answer to be found at the bottom of the page ;-)

Answer (score 80):

"Lazy loading" means that an entity will be loaded *only* when you **actually** accesses the entity for the *first* time.

The [pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) is like this:

```
public Entity getEntity() {
    if (entity == null) {
        entity = loadEntity();
    }
    return entity;
}
```

This saves the cost of preloading/prefilling *all* the entities in a large dataset beforehand while you after all actually don't need *all* of them.

In Hibernate, you can configure to lazily load a collection of child entities. The **actual** lazy loading is then done inside the methods of the [`PersistentSet`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/collection/PersistentSet.html) which Hibernate uses "under the hoods" to assign the collection of entities as `Set`.

E.g.

```
public class Parent {
    private Set<Child> children;

    public Set<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}
```

.

```
public void doSomething() {
    Set<Child> children = parent.getChildren(); // Still contains nothing.

    // Whenever you call one of the following (indirectly), 
    // Hibernate will start to actually load and fill the set.
    children.size();
    children.iterator();
}
```

Answer (score 28):

Martin Fowler defines the [Lazy Load](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html) pattern in [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#eaa) as such:

> *An object that doesn't contain all of the data you need but knows how to get it.*

So, when loading a given object, the idea is to not *eager load* the related object(s) that you may not use immediately to save the related performance cost. Instead, the related object(s) will be loaded only when used.

This is not a pattern specific to data access and Hibernate but it is particularly useful in such fields and Hibernate supports lazy loading of one-to-many associations and single-point associations (one-to-one and many-to-one) also under certain conditions. 
Lazy interaction is discussed in more detail in [Chapter 19](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/performance.html) of the Hibernate 3.0 Reference Documentation.

Answer (score 21):

Bydefault lazy loading is true.Lazy loading means when the select query is executed it will not hit the database. It will wait for getter function i.e when we required then ,it will fetch from the datbase.
for example:
You are a parent who has a kid with a lot of toys. But the current issue is whenever you call him (we assume you have a boy), he comes to you with all his toys as well. Now this is an issue since you do not want him carrying around his toys all the time.
So being the rationale parent, you go right ahead and define the toys of the child as LAZY. Now whenever you call him, he just comes to you without his toys.

Answer (score 15):

In layman's language, it is like you are making a cake and you will need 5-10 ingredients from fridge. You have two options, get all ingredients from fridge and put it on your kitchen platform, or bring the item you want when you need.

Similarly, in eager loading, you fetch all information about bean and its related classes (not child or is-a relation but has a relationship, i.e. cake has flour, has milk, has cream etc), and in case of lazy loading, first you bring only its identifier and values that are coming from same table (necessary ingredients that first you will need in your bowl in case of cake). All information that is coming from other tables will be fetched as and when required/used.

Answer (score 13):

Lazy fetching decides whether to load child objects while loading the Parent Object. 
You need to do this setting respective hibernate mapping file of the parent class. 
`Lazy = true` (means not to load child) 
By default the lazy loading of the child objects is true.

This make sure that the child objects are not loaded unless they are explicitly invoked in the application by calling `getChild()` method on parent.In this case hibernate issues a fresh database call to load the child when `getChild()` is actully called on the Parent object.

But in some cases you do need to load the child objects when parent is loaded. 
Just make the lazy=false and hibernate will load the child when parent is loaded from the database.

Example : 
If you have a TABLE ? EMPLOYEE mapped to Employee object and contains set of Address objects. 
Parent Class : Employee class,
Child class : Address Class

```
public class Employee { 
private Set address = new HashSet(); // contains set of child Address objects 
public Set getAddress () { 
return address; 
} 
public void setAddresss(Set address) { 
this. address = address; 
} 
}
```

In the Employee.hbm.xml file

```
<set name="address" inverse="true" cascade="delete" lazy="false"> 
<key column="a_id" /> 
<one-to-many class="beans Address"/> 
</set>
```

In the above configuration. 
If `lazy="false"` : - when you load the Employee object that time child object Address is also loaded and set to setAddresss() method. 
If you call employee.getAdress() then loaded data returns.No fresh database call.

If `lazy="true"` :- This the default configuration. If you don?t mention then hibernate consider lazy=true. 
when you load the Employee object that time child object Adress is not loaded. You need extra call to data base to get address objects. 
If you call `employee.getAdress()` then that time database query fires and return results. Fresh database call.

Comment: Employee and Address doesn't have Parent-Child relation in this scenario. It is **'has-a' relationship**!

Comment: This is aggregation not inheritance.

Answer (score 10):

Lazy loading allows you to defer the association retrieval or to have a better control over the fetching strategy.

When you use EAGER loading, you define a global fetch plan which cannot be overridden at query time, meaning you are limited to a decision you took while designing your entity model. The [EAGER fetching is a code smell](http://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/), because the fetching strategy is a query-time policy and it might differ from a business use case to another.

The [fetching strategy](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-strategy/) is a very important aspect, as too much EAGER fetching can cause serious performance related issues.

Answer (score 9):

Lazy Loading? Well, it simply means that child records are not fetched immediately, but automatically as soon as you try to access them.

Answer (score 4):

Lazy setting decides whether to load child objects while loading the Parent Object.You need to do this setting respective hibernate mapping file of the parent class.Lazy = true (means not to load child)By default the lazy loading of the child objects is true. This make sure that the child objects are not loaded unless they are explicitly invoked in the application by calling getChild() method on parent.In this case hibernate issues a fresh database call to load the child when getChild() is actully called on the Parent object.But in some cases you do need to load the child objects when parent is loaded. Just make the lazy=false and hibernate will load the child when parent is loaded from the database.Exampleslazy=true (default)Address child of User class can be made lazy if it is not required frequently.lazy=falseBut you may need to load the Author object for Book parent whenever you deal with the book for online bookshop.

Answer (score 3):

> Lazy loading is a design pattern
>   commonly used in computer programming
>   to defer initialization of an object
>   until the point at which it is needed.
>   It can contribute to efficiency in the
>   program's operation if properly and
>   appropriately used

Wikipedia

Link of [Lazy Loading](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html) from hibernate.org

Answer (score 2):

Well it simply means loading data you need currently instead of loading whole bunch of data at once which you won't use now. Thereby making application load time faster than usual.

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, none of answers talk about how it is achieved by hibernate behind the screens.

**[Lazy loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)** is a design pattern that is effectively used in hibernate for performance reasons which involves following techniques.

---

**1. Byte code instrumentation**:

Enhances the base class definition with hibernate [hooks](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/collection/PersistentList.html) to intercept all the calls to that entity object.

Done either at compile time or run[load] time

1.1 **Compile time**

- Post compile time operation
- Mostly by maven/ant plugins

1.2 **Run time**

- If no compile time instrumentation is done, this is created at run time
     Using libraries like [javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/)

**[2. Proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340606/what-does-the-hibernate-proxy-object-contain)**

The entity object that Hibernate returns are proxy of the real type.

See also:
[Javassist. What is the main idea and where real use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297565/javassist-what-is-the-main-idea-and-where-real-use)

Answer (score 1):

Hiberante supports the feature of lazy initialization for both entities and collections.
Hibernate engine loads only those objects that we are querying for does not other entites or collections.

lazy="false" by default loading initialization mention for the only child is lazy.in case of true that is parent is loading does not support child

Answer (score 1):

Lazy setting decides whether to load child objects while loading the Parent Object.You need to do this setting respective hibernate mapping file of the parent class.Lazy = true (means not to load child)By default the lazy loading of the child objects is true.