# hibernate and selective lazy loading

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

i have the following class structure mapped to my database, note in my diagram b is a one to many child of A, etc.

```
a
-b
--c
-d
--e
---f
---g
```

now, when i get my result set back from hibernate, i plug it into jibx to be marshalled and sent to the client.  my problem is when jibx tries to access the lazy load records, i get an exception because by that point its disconnected from the hibernate session.

now to make it even worse, there are transactions where i want to have all records of class a, b, c, d, but none of e, f, g.  but the next query may want all of a, d, e, f, g and none of b, or c and the next query all of a, d, g and none of the rest.

so, my DAO class looks like this

```
public class SurveyNameDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport
{
public List<SurveyName> getPermittedSurveys(String userName)
    {
        StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
        sql.append("select distinct sn ");
        sql.append("from SurveyName as sn, SurveyNameStore name_store ");
        sql.append("where name_store.showStoreLocation.storeName in (select ng.pnName ");
        sql.append("from NukeGroups as ng, NukeUsers as nu ");
        sql.append("where nu.pnName = '" + userName + "')");

        SurveyName loc = null;
        List l = getHibernateTemplate().find(sql.toString());

        return l;

    }
}
```

basic question is how can i modify this method (and many like it) where i can add some kind of indicators saying to load the return class in the manner i spoke above and then completely disconnect from hibernate and forget about lazy loading for when i send it to jibx.

Comment: Recommend replacing the variables in your query with a, b, c,... as in the diagram above so we can understand how the relationships relate to the query. Other than that, this is a little more SQL than I do on a regular basis so I don't know that I could help without a bit more effort than practical =)

Comment: its not an issue with the HQL query, its has to do with telling hibernate how to load the result into its classes.

Answer (score 0):

By default hibernate loads the child objects Lazily. That means, Only the object queried will be loaded, i.e. in your example, the ***SurveyName*** object will be loaded.

Assuming ***SurveyName*** corresponds to entity ***A*** in the tree you've shown above, only the id's of ***B*** and ***D*** which are the directly referenced objects in ***A*** will be loaded.

You can read more about this [What is lazy loading in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192242/what-is-lazy-loading-in-hibernate) and [Explanations of lazy loading](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SomeExplanationsOnLazyLoadingone-to-one).

As for your question, you need to fetch the referenced objects inside the session. So in your example you need to iterate over the ***list l*** and fetch the ***SurveyNameStore***  objects on each item in the list so that they are loaded.

After this, you can pass the ***SurveyName*** object and the ***SurveyNameStore*** reference will be available to send to the client.

Similarly you load all the objects you need in each method separately.

I don't have your class structure, so i can't give you the exact solution, but working on these lines should solve your problem, if you've not solved it already.

Comment: doesn't matter now.  I convinced the client to throw hibernate to the street and rewrite the application in straight JDBC.  already in the modules we have rewritten, we have seen the number of bugs drop to a fraction of what we were encountering before.  i will never use hibernate again, jdbc is so much easier.

Comment: in my experience, hibernate has made the basic stuff very easy, but the custom/complicated requirements or boundary cases make things quite problematic. Good call!