# Error creating bean with name 'entityManager"

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

iv'e searched this question and tried adding the pom dependency (the jaxb 2.3.0) but it still hasn't fixed this error. Im new to Spring so please bear with me. I get this error when I try to run the test that comes with Spring boot as well as trying to run the run the package.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1087) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127) ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) ~[spring-test-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) ~[spring-test-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) ~[spring-test-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) ~[spring-test-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) ~[spring-test-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) ~[spring-test-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89) ~[.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41) ~[.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541) ~[.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763) ~[.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463) ~[.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209) ~[.cp/:na]
```

--

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
package coffee;

import javax.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PUBLIC, force=true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class About {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private final Long id;
@NotEmpty
private final String name;
@NotEmpty
private final String description;
private final byte[] image;
```

}

```
package coffee.controller;

import coffee.*;
import coffee.data.AboutRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;



@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="abouts",
                produces="application/json",
                consumes="application/json")
@CrossOrigin(origins="*")
public class AboutController {
private AboutRepository aboutRepo;

public AboutController(AboutRepository aboutRepo) {
    this.aboutRepo = aboutRepo;
}

@GetMapping
public Iterable<About> getAbouts() {
    return aboutRepo.findAll();
}

@GetMapping("/{aboutId}")
public ResponseEntity<About> aboutById(@PathVariable("aboutId") Long id) {
    Optional<About> optAbout = aboutRepo.findById(id);
    if (optAbout.isPresent()){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(optAbout.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}

@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public About postAbout(@RequestBody About about) {
    return aboutRepo.save(about);
}

@PutMapping("/{aboutId}")
public About putAbout(@RequestBody About about) {
    return aboutRepo.save(about);
}

@DeleteMapping("/{aboutId")
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void deleteEvent (@PathVariable("aboutId") Long aboutId) {
    try {
        aboutRepo.deleteById(aboutId);
    }catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
    }
}
```

}

```
package coffee.data;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import coffee.*;

public interface AboutRepository extends CrudRepository<About, Long> {

}
```

Like i said I have been searching and trying the posted answers but it seems to not work for me.

Comment: Could you share your configuration for jpa?

Comment: i am using the spring boot jpa dependency with no additional configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure spring data jpa using your application.properties file or custom configuration java class.

You can refer to this tutorial :

https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa

Just add this dependency to your pom.xml:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist/3.23.1-GA

Comment: i thought because im using spring boot it would take care of the configuration for me? i have added explicit configuration to the properties file but the problems still persists

Comment: It will create you the default configuration. It will take care but what properties you need to configure inject etc it don’t know

Comment: spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

Comment: these are the properties ive added and it still doesnt work

Comment: You are using java 9?

Comment: i am using java 11

Comment: Updated answer)

Comment: wow youre a boss, is there an explanation to how that dependency gets it to work?

Comment: You can refer to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297565/javassist-what-is-the-main-idea-and-where-real-use