# bidirectional one-to-many with jointable

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having some issues getting a bidirectional one-to-many association working with JoinTables. This is what I got:

Class A:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name="join_table", 
    JoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="a_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="b_id")}
)
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<B> getBs() {
    return bs;
}
```

Class B:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(name="join_table", 
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="b_id", insertable=false,updatable=false)},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="a_id", insertable=false,updatable=false)})
public A getA() {
    return a;
}
```

If I create a instance of A and B, add the instance of B to A and save. It works. But when I reload the instance of A and try and access the set of Bs it throws a LazyInitializationError with the message "illegal access to loading collection ".

Where am I going wrong here? :) Can anybody point me to a example of bidirectional association which uses a join table. And where the ownership is kept to Class A, I have searched though the documentation at hibernate.org but I cant seem to find it.

-Daniel

Comment: Why are you using a different join table in your derived entity (B)?

Comment: sorry, I updated the question. The reason was that I modified the actual two classes for the example (renamed them A and B basically :))

Comment: Ok. Please add the error you're getting to the question.

Comment: Was your issue resolved? I can not see any comments or accepted answers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your mapping are proper and that's why the entry is getting saved in the Database. The issue in fetching is **because of the [Lazy Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192242/what-is-lazy-loading-in-hibernate)**.

To solve it modify mapping of the class A as,

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="join_table", 
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="a_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="b_id")}
)
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<B> getBs() {
    return bs;
}
```

This will fire an additional query to the table B and initialize the collection. It might affect the performance depending on the no of entries in your defendant table.

Read the API [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-singleassoc-fetching) for more information.