# One-to-many hibernate mapping: related collection is empty

Tags: hibernate, collections, mapping, one-to-many

`User` relates to `Employee` as one-to-many.
The problem is the list of `Employee`s within [PeristentSet](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/collection/PersistentSet.html) is empty.
It's seen from debug.
And it's at least one `Employee` exists in DB for `User`.

sql:

```
create table users(
      id int not null primary key,
...
 constraint `emp_constr` foreign key(`empid`) references `employee`(`id`));
```

User bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class User {
    private long id;
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
...
```

user.hbm.xml config:

```
<list name="employees" cascade="all" inverse="false" fetch="join">
        <key>
            <column name="userid" not-null="true"/>
        </key>
        <index column="idx"/>
    <one-to-many class="entry.Employee"/>
</list>
```

DAO call:

```
@Transactional
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class)
            .list();
}
```

Are there mistakes in `.hbm.xml` file or I should add `setFetchMode()` to `DAO` explicitly?

**EDIT :**

I can get one sized collection only,in real it contains more elements with such config:

```
<list name="employees" table="employee" lazy="false">
        <key column="userid" not-null="true"/>
    <list-index column="idx"/>
    <one-to-many class="entry.Employee"/>
</list>
```

that's because `idx=0`
if `idx=7` collection size will be `8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case of **[Lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192242/what-is-lazy-loading-in-hibernate)** in hibernate.

```
<list name="employees" .... lazy="false" >
```

You need to add the `lazy="false"` to the list mapping. Read [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-mapping) for the hibernate reference.

Comment: i tried this config already,it's the same,size of related collection is 0.

Comment: ManuPK,see EDIT section,please.For now I can fetch related collection with one element only,but in real it contains 3.

Comment: Try with **set** or **bag** instead on **list**. Say you have entries at **idx** 0, 5, 8 then the item in the list at position 1 will be null.