# Hibernate LAZY fetch not initializing an instance

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, fetch

I encountered a problem with lazy association two days ago and still haven't found an explanation of such a behavior. 
Here is my simplified class hierarchy:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
public class A
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
    private Set<B> listB = new HashSet<B>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
public class B
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID")
    private A a;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)      // ERROR!
    // @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)  // OK
    @JoinColumn(name="C_ID")
    private C c;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="C")
public class C {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id; 
}
```

When I try to read simple structure from db: A->B->C i get the following results:

```
System.out.println(a.getId());                  // 1
for (B b : a.getListB()) {                      
    System.out.println(b.getId());              // 1
    C c = b.getC();
    System.out.println(c.getId());              // 0 !!!
}
```

As you can see instance of C is not properly initialized.
After changing fetch type from LAZY to EAGER for field c in class B everything works!

I suspect there is is some CGLIB magic, but can't find a clue nether in the specification nor in Google.
Could someone explain this?

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. My question was not correct. Sorry.
There was final modifier for getters and setters of my entitiy classes. It breaks single value associations like many-to-one.
Suppose I've missed some warnings in hibernate logs...
I think it would be better to throw an exception by hibernate for this case.

Answer (score 1):

In case you would like to understand lazy loading see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192242/what-is-lazy-loading-in-hibernate); it defines it pretty well.