# I have the FetchType.LAZY and hibernate objects are still loaded

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, hibernate-mapping, eager-loading

I have this relation in my "**Persona**" entity

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "persona")
private Empleado empleado;
```

In my "**Empleado**" entity I have this relation

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "empleado", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Trabajo> trabajos = new HashSet<Trabajo>();
```

And I have in my "**Trabajo**" entity this relation

```
@BatchSize(size = 100)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "trabajo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Atencion> atenciones = new HashSet<Atencion>();
```

And this login method provided by GoogleCode

```
@Override
public Persona acceder(String login, String password) {
    Search s = new Search();
    s.addFilterEqual("usuario", login);
    s.addFilterEqual("clave", password);
    return searchUnique(s);
}
```

When I get the result object it has loaded the objects who have the EAGER fecth, everything is OK except in the "**Trabajo**" entity the "*Atenciones*" set gets loaded either it has the LAZY fetch. How can I fix this?

In my Trabajo entity I have other @OneToMany relationships that has LAZY fetch and there still get loading objects I don't know why.

When I use the dozer mapperService, it maps all the entire tree objects and I can see all the objects that are not supposed to appear.

Comment: How do you diagnose that the atenciones are loaded eagerly?

Comment: @JBNizet i say that because when the dozer mapper its done i can see all the huge tree objects. I cann see your answered, so i think you get it before i answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice explanation about lazy loading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2192256/11092). What you are seeing may be proxy objects. Check sql fired to verify if the data is really loaded from db.Do not worry about it if there are no queries on table related to 'Atencion'

It might be possible that your dozer mapping is accessing 'atenciones' elements which is causing the records loaded from db.If you don't want that to happen, there should be a way to exclude certain fields from mapping.

Comment: Yeah, you were right, the solution is here http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/exclude.html

Answer (score 3):

Lazy loading doesn't mean that the data won't be loaded. It means that the data will only be loaded when you (or Dozer, in this case), asks for its value.

Suppose you have an entity Manager, with a OneToMany with an entity Worker. And suppose the association is lazy-loaded. Here's what will happen:

```
Manager manager = session.get(Manager.class, 1L); 
// the above line loads the manager data from the database, using a SQL query

List<Worker> workers = manager.getWorkers();
// the workers variable references a Hibernate-specific list which is lazy-loaded.
// It doesn't contain any data until a method is called on it

int size = workers.size();
// calling any method of the list will cause a SQL query to be executed. This
// SQL query will load the workers of the manager from the database, and fill the list
// finally, the size of the list will be returned.
```

It's lazy, because it's only loaded when you really needed.

So, if you don't want to return the workers with the manager when mapping it using Dozer, make sure that Dozer doesn't try to get the workers. There are two simple solutions to do that:

- don't use Dozer (which sucks, IMHO)
- map the `Manager` entity to a `ManagerDTO` class which doesn't contain a workers list.

Comment: ¿Which one you recommend to use and why dozer sucks :(? Is there a way to configure dozer for do not pass the worker list ? If I map the list manually it going to be a hell for me :D

Comment: I can not erase the list of my manager, i use it for other things, so i think that i've to map it manually sometimes. Im very thankfull for your response

Comment: I find that dozer sucks because it makes something that is trivial to do manually, but requires unwanted setter methods, breaking encapsulation and good design to do so. And it silently breaks if you rename a property in one class without renaming it in the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I had to `Join` to unrelated classes while using `Specification`. I didn't find an excellent way to Join them and put `@OneToOne` relation on a class one of these.
This way caused fetching unnecessary attributes and I just mapped them via `@ManyToOne` though I don't need a relationship.
Anyway, I solved my unnecessary fetching problem.

Note: I do not need the class mapped. So I don't call any get methods.