# JPA: Lazy loaded data also getting fetched when not called

Tags: java, jpa, specifications

I've 4 entities, in my existing code.

`School`, which is lazily fetching `Students`.

`Students`, which has lazy many-to-one relation with `SportsClub`.

`SportsClub`, which EAGER one-to-many relation with `SportsClubRule`.

Now I only want to fetch School & its Students for a particular school.

I'm using `JPA Specifications` to get this detail.

I understand that when I'll fetch students, a query will also be generated for associated SportsClub, since they are being eagerly fetched.

But in the generated queries I can see queries for SportsClubRule as well, whereas they are being lazily fetched, which I was not hoping and found it unnecessary.

So how can I avoid unnecessary call to SportsClubRule when only fetching Students. (Preferably using JPA Specifications only)

Below are the 4 entities.

Sorry for the all the annotations, I didn't wanted to miss any details.

**School.java**

```
import lombok.*;    // for auto getter setter
import ...

@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}, ignoreUnknown = true)
@Audited @Entity @Table(name = "SCHOOL")
public class School extends AuditEntity implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "school", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Student> students;

    // getters & setters
}
```

**Student.java**

```
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}, ignoreUnknown = true)
@Audited @Entity @Table (name = "STUDENT")
@IdClass(SchoolStudentId.class)
public class Student extends AuditEntity implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "school_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private School school;

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "students",
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<SportsClub> sportsClub = new HashSet<>();


}
```

**SportsClub.java**

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Entity @Audited
@Table(name = "SPORTS_CLUB")
public class SportsClub extends AuditEntity implements Serializable {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", nullable = false)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();

  @OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "sportsClub",
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<SportsClubRule> sportsClubRule = new HashSet<>();

}
```

**SportsClubRule.java**

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Audited
@Table(name = "SPORTS_CLUB_RULE")
public class SportsClubRule extends AuditEntity implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sports_club_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private SportsClubRules sportsClubRule;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "rule_id", nullable = false)
    private Rule Rule;                                  // This getting fetched by default.

}
```

Comment: Does it help if you use `@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY, optional = false)`?

Comment: @crizzis, thanks, But I tried, it didn't helped.

Comment: You need to mark Set<SportsClub> as LAZY in Student.java probably

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15054716/12647580