# Exception in JSP when populating a table with list

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, pojo

I have this jsp code .

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${UsersList}">
 <tr>
 <td><c:out value="${item.userId}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${item.userName}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${item.car}" /></td>  //Here , I am getting exception
 </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

The UserList consists of an attribute called "car" of datatype "Car"

Pojo Class class for Users:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable {

private int userId;
private Car car;
private Groups groupId;
private UserType userType;
private String userName;

//getters and setters
}
```

I am using Spring MVC Framework. On page load my app should show a table with the list of users . In controller I am querying for the list of users and I am adding it to the ModelAndView object

Controller code:

```
List<Users> userList = service.getUserList();  //this will get list of users
//System.out.println("Userlist ==" +userList.size()); 
mv.addObject("UsersList" , usersList);
//skipped remaining code
```

When I tried without car (tabledata tag) JSP is running without exception and showing the users list in the table . If I try to add car (tabledata tag) then I am getting an exception

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/pages/CreateUser.jsp at line 199 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/pages/CreateUser.jsp at line 199

196:<tr>
197:<td><c:outvalue="${item.userId}" /></td>
198:<td><c:out value="${item.userName}" /></td>
199:<!-- <td><c:out value="${item.car}" /></td> --> 
200:<td><c:out value="${item.modifiedDate}" /></td>
201:</tr>
202:</c:forEach>                                            


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWra    pper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:4    70)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutput    Model(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:3    03)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.j    ava:1244)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(Disp    atcherServlet.java:1027)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServl    et.java:971)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServle    t.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkSer    vlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java    :861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.ja    va:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no  Session
org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:149)
org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:195)
org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
com.bdp.pojo.Role_$$_javassist_11.toString(Role_$$_javassist_11.java)
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.OutSupport.out(OutSupport.java:178)
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.OutSupport.doStartTag(OutSupport.java:99)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.CreateUser_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fout_005f2(CreateUser_jsp.java:667)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.CreateUser_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(CreateUser_jsp.java:591)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.CreateUser_jsp._jspService(CreateUser_jsp.java:264)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframeweb.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using hibernate lazy initialization, whenever you return the main object to the JSP it will try to fetch sub classes. And this wont happen because session would be closed.

Therefore change your fetching strategy to the `Eager`:

On your car's getter method:

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

This will cause fetching `car` immediatly when you fetch the main class.

To make it on query:

```
 List<Users> items = session.createCriteria(Users.class)
                    .setFetchMode("car", FetchMode.JOIN).
                    .createAlias("car", "car").
                    .list();
```

Comment: I tried doing that way . But , It is reflecting on entire project. I am getting Exceptions.

Comment: What do you mean by "Exceptions". You can change fetch strategy during executing of query

Comment: Ohh !! I don't know that one . Can you give any good reference for that.

Answer (score 1):

You receive error `LazyInitializationException`. `Users` objects in a lazy `Car` object. `service.getuserlist();` method can bring in by **`fetch`** the `Car` objects.

**Fetching Strategies**

FetchType.LAZY is on demand

FetchType.EAGER is immediate

`@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)` when you do want to take the user object as object the car all the time.

`service.getUserList ()` please  write.

**EDIT :**

Example `getUserList` method:

```
public List<Users> getUserList(){
    String sql = " SELECT user from Users user left join fetch user.car ";
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: I tried your query but I din't got the actual value. I got an object like this `com.project.pojo.Car@74b02890`

Comment: this com.project.pojo.Car@74b02890  proxy object. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25340780/1638718

Comment: No error bro :) but not displaying the value .. displaying that object

Comment: Please write car object.

Comment: Car Pojo Class write.