# Gson and Jackson both fails to initialize a lazy collection

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson, gson

i have no deep knowledge of Gson/Jackson till now. Please bear with me. I have to convert my object into json string. i have tried both **Gson** and **Jackson**. My object has a collection which has Fetch by default which is Lazy load. When i get the object with `session.get` and convert using Gson's `gson.toJson(object);` it fails to initialize that lazy collection.

### 1. I don't want to fetch eager.

### 2. i don't want to ignore it either.

I just want any way that it should return null or empty whatever instead of messing with lazy load collection. Because as far as i know, if its hibernate dependent then it is impossible fetching it out of session. Is there any work around (in both Gson or Jackson) with this issue cox i don't want to **always** initialize collection(but sometimes for sure)

```
@Entity
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Item> itemList;
    //getter setter
}
```

And in main method

```
Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction t = s.getTransaction();
t.begin();
Category category = null;
try{
    category = s.get(Category.class, 1);
    t.commit();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    s.close();
}

try {
    Gson json = new Gson();
    String categoryString = json.toJson(category);
    System.out.println(categoryString);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

it throws

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.company.entity.Category.itemList, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: Can you please debug your code and check, if the object you are about to serialize is really transient and is no longer a proxy? GSON is implemented to ignore null values, so it should ignore a collection that is null. Yet, if you are having a proxy object, the collection is there, but it will fail with an exception, when you try to use it outside a session.

Comment: @thst how can i explicitly make an object transient or proxy after getting from hibernate session? can you please explain this? cox i am using @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) but error still persist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216547/converting-hibernate-proxy-to-real-object

Answer (score 1):

I will post an answer to this, because it is not a dupe of the questions cited here. There is another question targeting Jackson, but that answer covers only Jackson. [Hibernate and Jackson lazy serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678919/hibernate-and-jackson-lazy-serialization?rq=1)

Before you persist your object with `Gson`, you need to make sure, that your collections are no more filled with proxies and that the lazy collections are really `null` and not a proxy that will fail if not in a session (this is the `LazyInitializationException` you are receiving.

As presented in this question, you can ask hibernate to give you the implementation object instead of the proxy with this code (quoting from [Converting Hibernate proxy to real object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216547/converting-hibernate-proxy-to-real-object)):

```
public static <T> T initializeAndUnproxy(T entity) {
    if (entity == null) {
        throw new 
           NullPointerException("Entity passed for initialization is null");
    }

//    Hibernate.initialize(entity);
    if (entity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        entity = (T) ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer()
                .getImplementation();
    }
    return entity;
}
```

In your case, I suppose you do not want the `initialize()` call to happen, so I commented that line out.

Your code should now read:

```
   Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction t = s.getTransaction();
    t.begin();
    Category category = null;
    try {
        category = s.get(Category.class, 1);
        t.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        s.close();
    }

    try {
        // No more hibernate messing with my object...
        Category theRealThing = initializeAndUnproxy(category);

        Gson json = new Gson();
        String categoryString = json.toJson(theRealThing);
        System.out.println(categoryString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Update: As for the comment, your class is not a proxy anymore. Another suggestion is to use a custom Gson serializer.

I won't give a full example, but you can find a discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/google-gson/kDZjEXap_PE

Basically, you rgister a Gson type adapter for collection or list types. Then you use `Hibernate.isInitialized()` on the collection object. If it is, you will serialize it, if it isn't, you return null.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually Category itself is not proxy, it just contains itemList which is PersistentBag and i don't want to load it which means i dnt want hibernate to query database for its entry. It should just return null or empty.
In your code above, when i pass Category object to this function condition **entity instanceof HibernateProxy** fails.