# Why we use Set<Object> or List<Object> in Hibernate One-To-Many relationship rather than HashSet<Object> or ArrayList<Object>?

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, one-to-many

I've always seen people using interfaces of collection framework when there is a One-to-many relationship in Entity classes. For Example if Author has written many books then it Looks like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
private List<Book> books;
```

and why not

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
private ArrayList<Book> books;
```

Or

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
private Set<Book> books;
```

and not

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
private HashSet<Book> books;
```

So why to use interfaces and not implementations of collection framework?

Comment: For the same reasons you have interfaces in the first place. Doesn't matter if hibernate is used or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way is to use Interfaces rather than concrete types as Hibernate behind the scene injects it's own implementations ( like [`PersistenBag`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/collection/internal/PersistentBag.html), [`PersistentSet`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/collection/internal/PersistentSet.html) etc.) to provide it's lazy loading / dirty check and other magic. Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340606/what-does-the-hibernate-proxy-object-contain?rq=1) answer too.