# Why does my repository findAll() method also returns child objects?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring project using Spring JPA. I have a table for `Brands` and `Products`, and I have mapped them through `@ManyToMany` like so:

BRAND ENTITY:

```
@Entity
public class Brand{


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = 
"brand_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "brand_seq_gen", sequenceName = "ISEQ$$_73370", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "BRAND_ID")
private Long brandId;

@Column(name = "BRAND_NAME")
private String brandName;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
    CascadeType.ALL
})
@JoinTable(
    name = "BRAND_PRODUCT",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BRAND_ID", referencedColumnName = "BRAND_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PRODUCT_ID")
)
private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();    

 //CONSTRUCTORS, SETTERS, AND GETTERS
}
```

PRODUCT ENTITY:

```
@Entity
public class Product{


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "prod_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "prod_seq_gen", sequenceName = "ISEQ$$_73373", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
private Long productId;

@Column(name = "TYPE_DESCRIPTION")
private String typeDescription;

public Product() {
}

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Brand> brands = new HashSet<>();
//Setters, Getters, and Constructors
```

and for example, I would only want to get the information of `Brand` only (BRAND_ID and BRAND_NAME) without getting the products, how would I access only the brand's information? Thank you!

--EDIT 1--

I would like to access ALL brands without accessing the `products` on each brand. Is that possible? Or do I create another class?

--EDIT 2--

Here is a sample query when using `BrandRepository.findall()`

```
[ {
 "brandId" : 1,
  "brandName" : "Electrolux",
  "products" : [ {
    "productId" : 4,
    "typeDescription" : "Refrigerator"
  }, {
    "productId" : 3,
    "typeDescription" : "Washing Machine"
  } ]
}, {
  "brandId" : 2,
  "brandName" : "Midea",
  "products" : [ {
    "productId" : 4,
    "typeDescription" : "Refrigerator"
  }, {
    "productId" : 2,
    "typeDescription" : "Air Conditioner"
  }, {
    "productId" : 3,
    "typeDescription" : "Washing Machine"
  } ]
}, {
  "brandId" : 3,
  "brandName" : "Samsung",
  "products" : [ {
    "productId" : 1,
    "typeDescription" : "TV"
  }, {
    "productId" : 4,
    "typeDescription" : "Refrigerator"
  } ]
}, {
  "brandId" : 4,
  "brandName" : "LG",
  "products" : [ {
    "productId" : 1,
    "typeDescription" : "TV"
  } ]
} ]
```

What I want should only be the columns `brandId` and `brandName` without the `products` resulting from @ManyToMany relationship.

--Edit 4--
I found out through `logging` that the database is being queried two times to retrieve both tables which is why I think it might be better to just use `@Query` and a projection.

Comment: Please follow [the Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) when writing in Java. For method and variable names camelCase is the norm, for classes and interfaces - PascalCase. SNAKE_CASE is used only for static constants and enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to fetch just some entity properties is to use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

Back to your example, you could have a projection interface defined like that:

```
interface BrandNameAndId {
  Long getId();
  String getBrandName();
}
```

And a method like this in your Brand's repository:

```
List<BrandNameAndId > findAllProjectedBy();
```

Comment: There seems to be a compilation error upon trying to use `Collection<BrandNameAndId> allBrandNameAndId()` method, but I am able to put into the `Collection<BrandNameAndId> findByBrandName(String brandName)` into my @Repository

Comment: I tried using `@Query("SELECT * FROM BRAND_E", nativeQuery = true)` to method `Collection<BrandNameAndId> methodName()`, but the output is null. I also tried it to method `Collection<Brand> methodName()` but the output now includes `products` field of `Brand` entity.

Comment: @VianyManuel Please use `List<BrandNameAndId > findAllProjectedBy();` as repository method name (answer updated)

Answer (score 2):

Use hibernate lazy loading that will fetch only brands, not the child items(products).

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192242/what-is-lazy-loading-in-hibernate) to understand what the lazy loading means.

Comment: I'll quickly read on this! Thank you for your time and response.

Comment: So I use a function to get the Product?

Comment: Did you check properly if you are using fetch type as Lazy then also why products are getting loaded??

Comment: I would recomend before writing such a code please have a look at this example: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading

Comment: I'm probably reading it right, but I'm not fully understanding how to implement it. I'm using a `RestController` in calling the `findAll()` method, does that make a difference?

Comment: By the way, does the `private Set<Product_E> products = new HashSet<>();` need to have a setter/getter method?

Comment: yes setter is required as spring, and hibernate internally uses setters, and getters for data binding.

Comment: You can use `RestController`. this controller will by default provide the JSON data back to its caller.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to have spring.jpa.open-in-view=false in your application.properties file. If you have it set to true you will end up querying database when you call get method on your entity.

Comment: I think this solved the `FetchType.LAZY` problem, but it induced another problem: the server could no longer initialize a collection of role `products`

Comment: If lazy problem is solved then please use MartinBG solution with projections. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections , it should work :)