# How not to get the children of the children of the children... etc. in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, join, persistence, one-to-many

I probably misunderstood some basics of JPA. I got a kind of circular reference on objects returned...

I had a list of questions, each with a list of responses.
But with the JPA mapping i did, each response also have a question. 
See here :

```
@Entity
public class Question implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // A question has several responses
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Reponse> reponses;

@Entity
public class Reponse implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    // This is here to specify the join column key "question_id"
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private Question question;
```

As you see here, I have a question[0] which has a list of responses, but each has a question, which also have a list of responses and so on... :

[image]

How can i specify the join column key without having to bring the whole object and all his children and so on ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Joss

Comment: You need to use lazy loading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192242/what-is-lazy-loading-in-hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration you did the flow retrieves data in following order:

- `Question` object
- Related entities (namely `Response` objects) due to the `FetchType.EAGER`
- `Question`object again
- repeat all steps

This is since in "to one" association the `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` is used by default.

Lazy loading is then the answer, you have to set `FetchType.LAZY` in `Response` object over the `question` field as `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` in order to stop the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Update the question to `FetchType.LAZY`

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
private Question question;
```